# Vuetify 1.5 to 2: How to center radio buttons in v-radio-group with prop 'row'?

Tags: vue.js, layout, vuetify.js, web-frontend

I'm upgrading a project's Vuetify version from 1.5 to 2.6. In version 1.5, the original code is as follows:

```
<v-layout column align-center justify-center>
  <v-flex>
    <p class="headline">朝代选择:</p>
    <v-radio-group v-model="dynastySelected" row>
      <v-radio
        v-for="(dynasty, index) in dynastys"
        :key="index"
        :label="dynasty"
        :value="dynasty"
      ></v-radio>
    </v-radio-group>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

style effect of this: [original style effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuo1x.png)

I have tried to change something:

```
<v-row justify="center">
  <v-col>
    <p class="text-h5">朝代选择：</p>
    <v-radio-group v-model="dynastySelected" row>
      <v-radio
        v-for="(dynasty, index) in dynastys"
        :key="index"
        :label="dynasty"
        :value="dynasty"
      ></v-radio>
    </v-radio-group>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

but the style [current style effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9FIh.png) is different from the original one and I don't know how to make it look the same as the original.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sur your problem is to center the content. The difference between two image is one have a margin how "center" the element.
So you juste have to add some css to `<v-row>` something like that for example `margin: 0 48px`

Comment: @RaphaelRollet Sorry, maybe my description is not clear. This code is contained in v-container. In the first image, the p element and radio buttons are to the left, while in the second image, radio buttons is centered horizontally and the p element is aligned to the left of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comment i think i have a better understand, tell me if not.

But i understand in the both image everything have the same width but the content is align to the left on the first image.
In the second image is center and it's what you want to do.

With have multiple solution depend on what it's inside, the simplest is on the v-col add the css:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
```

You can wrap your content inside v-col in a div if it's cause trouble on your display.

Comment: Yes, you see what I mean. Thank you for your patient answer, unfortunately it doesn't work. I've updated the question description because I thought maybe I should ask it another way. You can take a look at your convenience, thank you very much!

Comment: It's difficult to help you because like i say we have multiples solution, with margin, flex, align .... i do a codepen on what i think you want https://codepen.io/deeluxe/pen/wvjOMdw

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I tried applying the css code you wrote to the v-col and the radio buttons are indeed centered horizontally, but so is the p element which I want to align to the left side of radio buttons.

Comment: @PolarisXu Sorry i didn't see the class is not set. I update the codepen the class have to be on the row not the col. If u want it on the col wrap your `<p>` and `radio-group` inside a div`. Don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: Oh it does work in codepen! But not work in my project… So strange! Anyway, I have accepted your answer, and thank you again.

Comment: Try to copy paste this code in your project, i'm pretty sur something is not exactly the same. You need to play with flexbox, you can try this to understand https://flexboxfroggy.com/